# Django namespaced URLs and parameters

Tags: python, django, url

I'm encountering an odd problem with namespaced url in Django, and I cannot find what I am doing wrong while it is working on simpler examples and using the

Basically, my project is made of two apps, user and model. In my general urls.py, I defined :

```
url(r'^model/', include('model.urls', namespace="model")),
url(r'^user/', include('user.urls', namespace="user")),
```

In the user.urls.py file, I defined the following url:

```
url(r'^duo/(?P<pseudo>[a-z]+)/$',views.duo, name='duo'),
```

The duo view is rather simple :

```
def duo(request,pseudo):
     print pseudo
     return render(request,"user/duo.html",locals())
```

Therefore, when I use in my templates:

```
{% url 'user:duo' lena %}
```

I expect the url to be resolved as /user/duo/lena. Instead, I got the following NoReverseMatch:

```
 Reverse for 'duo' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'user/duo/(?P<pseudo>[a-z]+)/$']
```

I take any guess to fix my mistake !

Comment: try adding the parameter `app_name='appname'` to each `include` in urls.py. e.g. `url(r'^model/', include('model.urls', namespace="model", app_name='model')),`

Comment: This does not change the NoReverseMatch error :-/

Comment: from the error, `lena` seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, [Pynchia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1830895/pynchia) and [Bernhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639054/bernhard) comments help me to fix my bug ! Now, I am using

```
"{% url 'user:duo' "lena" %}"
```

in my template and it's running smoothly ! Many thanks to you !

Comment: then `lena` is a literal, as I had asked before. Alright :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited according to the dicussion:
You need to quote your paramater. Also keyword parameters might make things clearer:

```
{% url 'user:duo' pseudo='lena' %}
```

If you don't quote the value, Django assumes this is a context variable and as `lena` is not a context variable in your case this evaluates to `None`. The error actually tells you, you didn't provide args or kwargs for the reverse lookup.

Comment: my urls are all quoted and they work fine. I have never tried without quotes. Will do

Comment: I just tried, but I got now a TemplateSyntaxError:
      Could not parse the remainder: ':duo' from 'user:duo'

Comment: Hm, I had the same issue (this is with Django 1.4, though) and using keyword args and not quoting the namespaced url name did help in my case.

Comment: As it is Django 1.8, probably some stuff have changed since then... args is not working neither as a keyword

Comment: Just checked the docs. Indeed 1.4 allowed none quoted view names, 1.8 requires to do so. The keyword arg should work in both versions, though. Did you try: `{%url 'user:duo' pseudo='lena' %}?

Comment: Yep, I just fix it and made an answer to my own question. Thanks for your input !